# How to change the default terminal to rxvt in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can I set rxvt as my default terminal in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install rxvt on your system and run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`.

Then choose rxvt, and that is finished.

Comment: That worked, but it doesn't get started from the `Accesories > Terminal` (Ubuntu Netbook Remix)? Do I have to put some lines in my `.bashrc`? I'm new to Linux...

Comment: Go to System/Preferences/Prefered Applications/System and choose your favorite terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Setting from command-line without keyboard choice:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/urxvt
```